# CanJS parseModels and data coercion

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-model

I think I may have an odd use case here. I've got a `Code` model with `code`, `title`, `description` attributes. Users are documenting work (healthcare), they enter the `code`, say `7`, and `7` always means that something particular happened, say "The patient was cured." Whatever, doesn't matter. Point is, I don't want to bother saving the `title` and `description` in every model, but I want to be able to pull them for displaying.

So the API delivers an array of codes like `[ 1, 13, "A4" ]`. I'm trying to use both [can.Model.parseModel](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.parseModel.html) and [can.Map.define](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Map.prototype.define.html) to coerce that array into `Code` models, but I'm having a hard time.

**Why is parseModel, parseModels never called in this example?** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnmgppua/)

```
Code = can.Model.extend({
  parseModel: function(data) {
    // return { code:data }
    console.log('Never hit!');
  },
  parseModels: function() {
    // ...
    console.log('Never hit!');
  }
},{
  _title: can.compute(function() {
    // return title from cached lookup
  })
});

Model = can.Model.extend({
  findAll: 'GET /Models'
},{
  define: {
    Codes: {
      Type: Code.List
    }
  }
});

can.fixture('GET /Models', function() {
  return [
    { Codes: [1,2,3] }, // I want to turn each number into an object
    { Codes: [4,5,6] },
    { Codes: [7,8,9] }
  ];
});

Model.findAll({});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.parseModels` is only called during retrieval of CRUD service data.

To make your example work, you have to make a Model.parseModel convert each Code array to an an array of objects.

Alternately, you could change Model's define.Codes.Type to something like:

```
Codes: {
  type: function(newVal){
    if(newVal instanceof Code.List) {
      return newVal
    } else {
      return new Code.List( newVal.map(function(num){ return {value: num}}) )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was one of my guesses. It would be nice if fixtures used parseModels as expected.

Comment: Fixture responses do run through parseModels. But only the parseModels of the model making the request. parseModels is only for manipulating Ajax data. Anything else should be done with the define plugin.